# What does "a pop" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, meaning-in-context

when we say "For entertainment, she couldn’t go to
the movies at $8 a pop", what "a pop" means?

Comment: a pop == apiece || each

Comment: General reference. http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pop_17#a-pop

Comment: I know the question doesn't ask for a history of the phrase but I am interested in its etymology - has anyone found anything definitive? Cursory Google searches have shown up nothing for me.

Comment: @AndyF You might rescue the question from being closed (or get it reopened) if you add that in.

Answer (score 9):

The OED’s definition 3c of *pop* is ‘A turn at doing something; an attempt; a go; a time’ and the earliest citation supporting this sense is dated 1839.